# Error in Trigger Update - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I am trying to define a trigger on the `Employee` table, so that if the `Salary` column of an `Employee` is updated, the `TaxDeduction` column in `TaxDetails` table should be updated.

Here is the trigger which I wrote:

```
create trigger tr_EmpTaxDetails
On Employee
For Update
As
    if Update (Salary)
    Begin
        Declare @SSN int;
        Declare @Salary money;
        Declare @TaxDeduction money;

        select @SSN = i.SSN from Inserted i
        select @Salary = Salary from Inserted where SSN = @SSN

        Update TaxDetails
        Set TaxDeduction = (TaxRate/100)* @Salary
        where EmpSSN = @SSN
    End
Go
```

When I execute

```
update Employee
set Salary = 35000
where SSN = 12334
```

I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Employee SSN ' to data type int

But `SSN` in `Employee` is of type `int`, just as the `EmpSSN` in `Taxdetails`

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: triggers MUST be Batch 'aware'. Yours isn't.

Comment: you do realise this trigger is only good if a single record is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's not the column SSN in Employee or EmpSSN in Taxdetails, it's another column  'Employee SSN ' which is the reason for conversion failure. please check do you have any column 'Employee SSN ' used in your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
create trigger tr_EmpTaxDetails
On Employee
For Update
As
if Update (Salary)

Begin
    Update TaxDetails 
    Set TaxDeduction = (TaxRate/100) * i.Salary
    from TaxDetails td 
    inner join inserted i on td.empssn = i.SSN
End
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo tables `Deleted` and `Inserted` might (and **will!**) contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
select @SSN = i.SSN from Inserted i
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Inserted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Inserted` !

So your code should basically be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmpTaxDetails
ON dbo.Employee
FOR UPDATE
AS        
     UPDATE td
     SET TaxDeduction = (td.TaxRate / 100) * i.Salary
     FROM dbo.TaxDetails td
     INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.SSN = td.EmpSSN 
     INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.SSN = td.EmpSSN 
     WHERE
        d.Salary <> i.Salary  -- update only rows where the "Salary" has changed
```